# When exactly did the Black Saints die in the manga?

Tags: saint-seiya

*I have recently started reading the original Saint Seiya manga (Italian edition), and I am slightly confused by the events surrounding the Black Saints' demise. This question contains unmarked spoilers for the story arc in question and the Silver Saints arc.*

During the battle at Mount Fuji, we see the four Bronze Saints besting their respective enemies, with at least Black Swan and both Black Dragons strongly implied to have died (Hyoga comments on this after Black Swan plucks off his eye and sends it to Ikki).

Immediately after, at the beginning of the Silver Saints arc, we find out that Asterion, Moses and Babel have killed three of the Black Saints (again?), while under the influx of an illusion that deceived them to think they were the real Bronze Saints.

My question now is:

Has Masami Kurumada or another authoritative source ever addressed the paradox of the Black Saints being apparently killed twice? Or is it a case of their "first death" being retconned a couple chapters later to help with the build-up of the Silver Saints arc?

A cursory search on Google didn't yield authoritative results on the topic, just some results on wikias that weren't explicative and/or just hypothetical in nature.

Asking **only about the manga**, as in the anime the circumstances surrounding the defeat of the Black Saints play out very differently.